# Handling microseconds in Spark Scala

Tags: java, scala, datetime, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I imported a PostgreSQL table into spark as a dataframe using Scala. The dataframe looks like

```
user_id | log_dt  
--------| -------    
96      | 2004-10-19 10:23:54.0    
1020    | 2017-01-12 12:12:14.931652
```

I am transforming this dataframe to have the data format for log_dt as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS`. To achieve this I used the following code to convert the log_dt to timestamp format using `unix_timestamp` function.

```scala
val tablereader1 = tablereader1Df.withColumn("log_dt",unix_timestamp(tablereader1Df("log_dt"),"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS").cast("timestamp"))
```

When I print to print the tablereader1 dataframe using the command `tablereader1.show()` I get the following result

```
user_id | log_dt  
--------| -------
96      | 2004-10-19 10:23:54.0
1020    | 2017-01-12 12:12:14.0
```

How can I retain the microseconds as part of the timestamp? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Update! Included solution for micro/nanoseconds using Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Milleseconds with `date_format()`

You can use Spark SQL [`date_format()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_format(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String)) which accepts Java [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns. `SimpleDateFormat` can parse till milleseconds only **with pattern "S"**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._ //to use $-notation on columns

val df = tablereader1Df.withColumn("log_dt", date_format($"log_dt", "S"))
```

---

## Update: Microseconds with LocalDateTime of Java 8

```
//Imports
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;

/* //Commented as per comment about IntelliJ
spark.udf.register("date_microsec", (dt: String) => 
   val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.n")
   LocalDateTime.parse(dt, dtFormatter).getLong(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND)
)
*/

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val date_microsec = udf((dt: String) => {
    val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.n")
    LocalDateTime.parse(dt, dtFormatter).getLong(ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND)
})
```

Check: [help in building DateTimeFormatter pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoGjU.png)

Use `ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND` instead of `ChronoField.MICRO_OF_SECOND` to fetch Nanosecond in UDF.

```
val df = tablereader1Df.withColumn("log_date_microsec", date_microsec($"log_dt"))
```

Comment: I used `val df = tablereader1Df.withColumn("log_dt", date_format(tablereader1Df("log_dt"), "S"))` instead. It worked. thanks

Comment: One concern I have here is that the date_format() function is only giving me millisecond precision. Is there a way I can get microsecond precision.

Comment: `import spark.implicits._` will resolve issue to access columns directly with **$**. Pls check the update.

Comment: @mrsrinivas This still does not handle microseconds unfortunately.  It can't be done with SimpleDateFormat and the java.util.Date doesn't even store that level of precision.

Comment: @puhlen: Update! Included solution for micro/nanoseconds using Java 8.

Comment: Intellij idea can not find `date_microsec` :( How add it?