# Reading a full timestamp into a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am trying to learn Spark and I am reading a dataframe with a timestamp column using the `unix_timestamp` function as below:

```
  val columnName = "TIMESTAMPCOL"
  val sequence = Seq(2016-01-20 12:05:06.999)
  val dataframe = {
    sequence.toDF(columnName)
  }
  val typeDataframe = dataframe.withColumn(columnName, org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp($"TIMESTAMPCOL"))
  typeDataframe.show
```

This produces an output:

```
+------------+
|TIMESTAMPCOL|
+------------+
|  1453320306|
+------------+
```

How can I read it so that I don't lose the ms i.e the `.999` part? I tried using `unix_timestamp(col: Col, s: String)` where s is the SimpleDateFormat, eg "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", without any luck.

Comment: `date_format` uses java simpledateformat internally so you will get full time in milli seconds as well. possible duplicated [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879125/handling-microseconds-in-spark-scala/41879869#41879869)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling microseconds in Spark Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879125/handling-microseconds-in-spark-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retain the milliseconds use `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"` format. You can use `date_format` like below.

```
val typeDataframe = dataframe.withColumn(columnName, org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format($"TIMESTAMPCOL","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
typeDataframe.show
```

This will give you

```
+-----------------------+
|TIMESTAMPCOL           |
+-----------------------+
|2016-01-20 12:05:06:999|
+-----------------------+
```