# Parse dates with microseconds precision with dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, time

I have a csv file:

```
Name;Date
A;2018-01-01 10:15:25.123456
B;2018-12-31 10:15:25.123456
```

I try to parse with Spark Dataframe:

```
val df = spark.read.format(source="csv")
    .option("header", true)
    .option("delimiter", ";")
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
```

But the resulting Dataframe is (wrongly) truncated at the millisecond:

```
scala> df.show(truncate=false)
+---+-----------------------+
|Nom|Date                   |
+---+-----------------------+
|A  |2018-01-01 10:17:28.456|
|B  |2018-12-31 10:17:28.456|
+---+-----------------------+


df.first()(1).asInstanceOf[Timestamp].getNanos()
res51: Int = 456000000
```

Bonus question: read with nanoseconds precision

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879125/handling-microseconds-in-spark-scala

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling microseconds in Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879125/handling-microseconds-in-spark-scala)

Answer (score 1):

.SSSSS means milliseconds not microseconds: 
[java.util.Date format SSSSSS: if not microseconds what are the last 3 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19223171/java-util-date-format-ssssss-if-not-microseconds-what-are-the-last-3-digits), 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
So if you need microseconds you should parse the date by custom code:
[Handling microseconds in Spark Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879125/handling-microseconds-in-spark-scala)

Bonus answer: SparkSQL store data in microseconds internally, so you could use string to store nanos or separate field or any other custom solution